# reorder does not reflect on the list in backpack for laravel

Tags: laravel-backpack

I added reordering items according to [the doc](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/advanced-features#section-reordering-and-nesting-items).

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Backpack\NewsCRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Admin\TagCrudController as OriginalTagCrudController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class TagCrudController extends OriginalTagCrudController
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->user = Auth::user();
            return $this->user->can('Blog') ? $next($request) : redirect(config('mycms.dashboard'));
        });

        $this->crud->allowAccess('reorder');
        $this->crud->enableReorder('name', 1);

    }
}
```

I am able to reorder items.

[image]

But it does not reflect on the list.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I needed to add the following.

```
$this->crud->orderBy('lft');
```